# What is Install-Module command in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

Various Microsoft articles refer to the Powershell command [Install-Module](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt125356.aspx), but I can't find any reference to what this actually is and it's not very amenable to googling. I have [psget](http://psget.net/) installed, so I have its version of Install-Module ... but I think that's not the Install-Module that everyone else is talking about.

Ah, I found [this Install-Module](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn807162.aspx). Is that a different one to the one that PsGet installs? If so should I uninstall PsGet so I get back to the default one?

Comment: "Is that a different one?" - No;  In the example `Install-Module` is used to install the `Azure Resource Manager`.  `Install-Module` itself is part of PowerShell 3.0 and `Azure Resource Manager` is part of PowerShell 5

Comment: Thanks @Ramhound - I have psget installed which adds an Install-Module command, so I assume that's overwritten the Install-Module that comes with PS.

Comment: I would assume that, not guaranteed, but if the module itself is added its a safe bet.

Comment: blog post https://til.secretgeek.net/powershell/psget_conflicts_with_PowerShellGet.html

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I had previously installed [PSGet](http://psget.net/) which had overwritten my version of `Install-Module`. You can check this by running `help install-module` and see which version it refers to.

I couldn't find uninstall documentation for PSGet so I removed it by deleting the folder `C:\Users\Rory\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PSGet`. Now `help install-module` refers to the microsoft version.

Comment: This is correct way to uninstall any module if it does not have references. PsGet by default does not have any, so should be fine just to remove it.

Comment: You will probably need to restart your Powershell command window for this to take effect.

Comment: Tn my computer, psget was installed under C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules

Answer (score 9):

You can work around the clash by **prefixing the command with the module name**:

PsGet installed and getting in the way:

```
C:\repos> install-module csproj
Module csproj was not found in central repository
At C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PsGet\PsGet.psm1:694 char:13
+             throw "Module $Module was not found in central repository ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (Module csproj w...tral repository:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Module csproj was not found in central repository
```

using the qualified name:

```
C:\repos> powershellget\install-module csproj

Untrusted repository
You are installing the modules from an untrusted repository. If you trust this repository, change its InstallationPolicy value by running
the Set-PSRepository cmdlet. Are you sure you want to install the modules from 'PSGallery'?
[Y] Yes  [A] Yes to All  [N] No  [L] No to All  [S] Suspend  [?] Help (default is "N"): y
C:\repos>
```

Thanks to http://windowsitpro.com/blog/dealing-cmdlet-name-conflicts

Module name obtained from reading the url of the documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/PowerShellGet/install-module

More info: https://andrwwatt.wordpress.com/2006/05/13/coping-with-a-powershell-naming-clash/